# Storing and printing out linked list pointer contents from binary file

Tags: c, pointers, printing, linked-list

The user is to put in commands that then will add integers to a linked list, then will save them into a file and then finally print the contents of that file out. While ive got it to essentially work im having the issue of it not working while the program is running, so while it does add to the file it doesn't do so during runtime. so i can use the command `s` and then use the command `l` to be able to see the new contents i just saved to the file. How can i accomplish this? Also how can i detect if there are already contents in the file and if so print a `,` first.

**knapsack-shell.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "knapsack.c"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1000
void removeSpaces(char *str1)
{
    char *str2;
    str2=str1;
    while (*str2==' ') str2++;
    if (str2!=str1) memmove(str1,str2,strlen(str2)+1);
}

int main()
{
    listitemptr k2 = NULL;
    char input[100];
    char command;
    int i, returnval = 0;
    char filename[250];
    char userfile[260];
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    char *error;
    int totalRead = 0;
   for (;;) {
       FILE* pf = NULL;
        fprintf(stdout, "> ");
        if (!fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin))
            break;
        i = strspn(input, " \t\n");  /* skip blanks */
        command = input[i++];

        if (command == 'q' && input[i] == '\n')
            break;
        if (command == 'p') {
            KnapsackPrint(&k2);
            continue;
        }
        if (command == 'a') {
            int item;
            if (sscanf(input + i, "%i", &item) != 1) {
                error = input + i;
                removeSpaces(error);
                fprintf(stderr, "Error: Bad item \"%s\"\n", strtok(input + i, "\n"));

                continue;
            }
            KnapsackAdd(&k2, item);
            KnapsackPrint(&k2);
            continue;
        }
        if (command == 'r') {

            int item;
            if (sscanf(input + i, "%i", &item) != 1) {
                error = input + i;
                removeSpaces(error);
                fprintf(stderr, "Error: Bad item \"%s\"\n", strtok(input + i, "\n"));
                continue;
            }

            if(KnapsackRemove(&k2, item) == -1){
                fprintf(stderr, "Error: item %d does not exist in knapsack\n", item);
                continue;
            }else{
            KnapsackPrint(&k2);
            continue;
            }

        }
        if(command == 's'){
            if(( pf = fopen(input + i, "a")) != NULL){
                error = input + i;
                removeSpaces(error);
                KnapsackPrint2(&k2, pf);
                fprintf(stdout, "stored in file \"%s\"\n", strtok(input+i, "\n"));
            }
            continue;
        }
        if(command == 'l'){
            if((pf = fopen(input + i, "r")) != NULL){
                error = input + i;
                removeSpaces(error);
                fprintf(stdout, "loaded from file \"%s\"\n", strtok(input+i, "\n"));

                while(fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, pf) != NULL){
                    totalRead = strlen(buffer);

                    buffer[totalRead -1] = buffer[totalRead -1] == '\n' ? '\0' : buffer[totalRead -1];

                    printf("%s\n", buffer);
                }

            }
            continue;
        }
        else{
        fprintf(stderr, "unknown command: %s", input);
        fprintf(stdout, "> ");
        }

    }
    return returnval;
}
```

**knapsack.c**

```
#include "knapsack.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

listitemptr KnapsackAdd(listitemptr *knapsack, int item){
   if(*knapsack==NULL){//empty list
       listitemptr newest= malloc(sizeof(struct listitem));
       newest->item=item;
       newest->count=1;
       newest->next=NULL;
       *knapsack = newest;
       return newest;
   }else{
       listitemptr current=*knapsack;
       listitemptr prev=NULL;
       while(current!=NULL){
           if(current->item == item){
               current->count=current->count+1;
               break;
           }else if(current -> item > item){
               listitemptr new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct listitem));
               new_node-> item = item;
               new_node-> count= 1;
               new_node-> next = current;
               if(prev != NULL ){
                   prev->next = new_node;
               }else {
                   *knapsack = new_node;

               }
               break;

           }
           prev=current;
           current=current->next;
       }
       if(current==NULL){
           listitemptr newest= malloc(sizeof(struct listitem));
           newest->item=item;
           newest->count=1;
           newest->next=NULL;
           prev->next=newest;
           return newest;
       }
       return current;
   }
}

int KnapsackRemove(listitemptr *knapsack, int item){
   if(*knapsack==NULL)
       return -1;
   listitemptr present=*knapsack;
   listitemptr previous=NULL;

   while(present!=NULL){
       if(present->item==item){
           if(present->count>1){
               present->count=present->count-1;
           }else{
               if(previous==NULL){ //delete at head
                   *knapsack=present->next;
               }else{
                   previous->next=present->next;
                   free(present);
               }
           }
           break;
       }
       previous=present;
       present=present->next;
   }

   return 0;
}

void KnapsackPrint(const listitemptr *knapsack){
   if(*knapsack==NULL)
       printf("knapsack: \n");
   else{
       listitemptr temp=*knapsack;
       printf("knapsack:");
       while(temp!=NULL){
           if((temp->next) == NULL){
               printf(" %d (%d)", temp->item, temp->count);
               break;
           }else{
           printf(" %d (%d),",temp->item,temp->count);
           temp=temp->next;
         }

       }
       printf("\n");
   }
}

unsigned int KnapsackItemCount(const listitemptr *knapsack, int item){
   if(*knapsack==NULL)
       return 0;
   listitemptr temp=*knapsack;
   while(temp!=NULL){
       if(temp->item==item)
           return temp->count;
       temp=temp->next;
   }
   return 0;  
}

unsigned int KnapsackSize(const listitemptr *knapsack){

   if(*knapsack==NULL){

       return 0;
   }

   listitemptr temp=*knapsack;
   unsigned int sum=0;
   while(temp!=NULL){
       sum+=temp->count;
       temp=temp->next;
    }
   return sum;


}

listitemptr KnapsackPrint2(const listitemptr *knapsack, FILE* fp){
   if(*knapsack==NULL)
       printf("knapsack: \n");
   else{
       listitemptr temp=*knapsack;
       fprintf(fp, "knapsack:");
       while(temp!=NULL){
           if((temp->next) == NULL){
               fprintf(fp, " %d (%d)", temp->item, temp->count);
               break;
           }else{
           fprintf(fp, " %d (%d),",temp->item,temp->count);
           temp=temp->next;
         }

       }
       printf("\n");
       return temp;
   }
}
```

Comment: You may want to close the file after having written to it.

Comment: oh... cant believe i missed that one. Thank you. Fixed that problem real quick. How can i check the file though and if its not empty put in a comma?

Comment: After closing, you can open it and read from it to check (and close again when done).

Comment: pointers are meaningless in a file. so how are you serializing the linked list nodes when writing them to the file?

Comment: what is the contents of `knapsack.h` and how is `listitemptr` defined.  BTW: it is a very poor programming practice to hide pointers in typedef statements

Comment: Tell my professor that then user3629249, He gave us the typedef pointers and specifically told us not to change them. Fixed my issue tho